# Alternative row coloring in html table with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have an table which is filled with values using ng-repeat. I need to color the rows of table alternatively with green and yellow color. I tried it out the following way without ng-repeat and it works.

```css
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd)
    {
        background: yellow !important;
    }

    .table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(even)
    {
        background: green !important;
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <div><table class="table table-striped">
        <thead style="border: 1px solid">
            <tr>
                <th>Heading</th>                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr>
                <td>{{value.val1}}</td>
             </tr>
          <tr>
                <td>{{value.val2}}</td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
                <td>{{value.val3}}</td>
            </tr>            
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
  <html>
```

But it is not working while using ng-repeat as follows(all rows are in yellow itself). Please help.Thanks in advance.

```css
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd)
    {
        background: yellow !important;
    }

    .table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(even)
    {
        background: green !important;
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <div><table class="table table-striped">
        <thead style="border: 1px solid">
            <tr>
                <th>Heading</th>                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="value in values">
           <tr>
                <td>{{value.val1}}</td>
             </tr>
                      
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
  <html>
```

Comment: Give ng-class a try. It should work as expected. I suspect that angular only creates the value after the first render, which causes css to not apply the style.

Comment: i can see both seems fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class to your rows dynamically and then give the style you want.

```
<tr class="myrow">

$(".myrow:odd").addClass("odditem");
$(".myrow:even").addClass("evenitem");
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should give ng-repeat="value in values" to tr not to tbody. You ng-repeat on body will repeat body element.

Comment: If you see the code, he wants a row for each value in the iterated object, so his HTML is correct.

Comment: If you want a row for each value in object then you should use ng-repeat on tr not tbody because using re-repeat on tbody generated html will be as like below
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> value1</td>
<tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> value2</td>
<tr>
</tbody>
like this.
Thats why it is attaching always odd type of class to tr.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the directive ng-class-odd="'classname'".

```
<html>
  <div>
     <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead style="border: 1px solid">
            <tr>
                <th>Heading</th>                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="value in values">
           <tr class="row-color" ng-class-odd="'odd'">
                <td>{{value.val1}}</td>
             </tr>
          <tr class="row-color" ng-class-odd="'odd'">
                <td>{{value.val2}}</td>
            </tr>
          <tr class="row-color" ng-class-odd="'odd'">
                <td>{{value.val3}}</td>
            </tr>            
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
  <html>
```

then in your css you could do the following

```
.row-color {
    background: green;
}

.row-color.odd {
    background: yellow;
}
```

This also gets rid of your !important which is usually regarded as bad practice.

Comment: I removed the table-striped class too. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

While I think the solution for OP would be moving the `ng-repeat` from `<tbody>` to `<tr>`, because it matches his intended structure without `ng-repeat`; it is entirely possible to color alternatively by using css alone when the `ng-repeat` is on the `<tbody>` layer.

```css
tbody:nth-of-type(odd)>tr {
  background-color: pink;
}

tbody:nth-of-type(even)>tr {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>row1</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>row2</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>row3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```